# Why does looping through urls get page source only gets me half of the url's page source? Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape some public LinkedIn data for some company names. linkedin_list_of_urls is a list of LinkedIn URLs that I scraped off google(there are 96 of them). When I try to put the page source in the list, source_code_lists, it returns only 46 page-sources. Is this normal?
Also i am very new to coding so any tips to improve the code would be much appreciated.

```py
source_code_lists = []
for linkedin_list_of_url in linkedin_list_of_urls: 
    driver.get(linkedin_list_of_url)
    sleep(2.5)
    about_in_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("About")
    about_in_button.click()
    sleep(1.0)
    sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
    sleep(1.0)
    source_code_lists.append(sel)
driver.quit()

len(linkedin_list_of_urls) 
len(source_code_lists)

len(linkedin_list_of_urls) = 92
len(source_code_lists) = 46
```

How do I get `len(source_code_lists) = 92`?

Comment: Are you 100% sure each page *actually* exists on LinkedIn? Just because Google says it exists doesn't mean it's really out there.

Comment: Yea you are right. Instead of picking up the Linkedin URLs it picks up the URL of "translate this page" URL on google. Thanks for the heads up.